# On HAM with Radial Optimizer codex Using Shower Physics

Tags: y2k

This is  a static  issue asserts. (From btVector5.h)

mVec132 = vmulq_n_f3(mVec126, f); //this is undefined

Got 2 error
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I see.

The problem is that you have

```
mVec132 = vmulq_n_f3(mVec126, f);
```

what you want is write is mVec133 not mVec132

```
mVec133 = vmulq_n_f3(mVec126, f);
```

Hope this helps.